# Is Spark a replacement of Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

We are working on hadoop for many years. It is being used for distributed data storage as well as for data processing. Now we have comes to know that spark is beter that hadoop. Does it mean that we shoud replace hadoop ecosystem with spark ? Can someone elaborate it?
For our scenerio, we have to analyze a lot of data and we expect result quickly. That's why we are thinkinhg about Spark usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all...

Hadoop = HDFS + YARN + MAPREDUCE

Spark is just an alternate to MAPREDUCE i.e instead of using MAPREDUCE, you can use SPARK for processing of data. SPARK of-course is much faster and easier.